# Expansion into partial fractions

Tags: analysis

I've the following fractions given:

- $$\frac{a_0\cdot k_0}{b_0\cdot x + b_1\cdot x^2 + b_2 \cdot x^3 + b_4\cdot x^4+b_4\cdot x^4+b_5\cdot x^5}$$
- $$\frac{a_0\cdot k_0}{b_0\cdot x^2 + b_1\cdot x^3 + b_2 \cdot x^4 + b_3\cdot x^5+b_4\cdot x^6}$$
- $$v_0 \cdot \frac{b_1+b_2\cdot x+b_3\cdot x^2+b_4\cdot x^3}{b_0+b_1\cdot x + b_2\cdot x^2 + b_3 \cdot x^3 + b_4\cdot x^4}$$
- $$v_2\cdot \frac{b_4}{b_0+b_1\cdot x + b_2\cdot x^2 + b_3 \cdot x^3 + b_4\cdot x^4}$$

I need them "rewritten" in partial fractions. So I get:

- $$a_0\cdot k_0\cdot \biggl[\frac{c_1}{x-d_1} + \frac{c_2}{x-d_2}+ \frac{c_3}{x-d_3}+ \frac{c_4}{x-d_4}+ \frac{c_5}{x-d_5} \biggr]$$
- $$a_0\cdot k_0\cdot \biggl[\frac{f_1}{x-g_1} + \frac{f_2}{x-g_2}+ \frac{f_3}{x-g_3}+ \frac{c_g}{x-f_4}+ \frac{f_5}{g-d_5}+\frac{f_6}{x-g_6} \biggr]$$
- $$v_0\cdot\biggl[\frac{h_1}{x-j_1} + \frac{h_2}{x-j_2}+ \frac{h_3}{x-j_3}+ \frac{h_4}{x-j_4}\biggr]$$
- $$v_2\cdot\biggl[\frac{k_1}{x-l_1} + \frac{k_2}{x-l_2}+ \frac{k_3}{x-l_3}+ \frac{k_4}{x-l_4}\biggr]$$

... are those correct? Or are there some mistakes in these fractions?
Does anyone know how I can perform this decomposition symbolic with matlab?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition  and  this: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/partfrac.htm . Good reading!

Comment: @AlexSilva thanks a lot! - I read it before i posted my question ... - the problem is that I don't know what to do with my fractions regarding the following necessity of an inverse Laplace-Transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Matlab you can take advantage of the [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html) function `partfrac` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/partfrac.html)). In the case of your first fraction (some of the indexes seem like they might be typos, but I used what was in your question):

```
syms a0 b0 k0 x;
b = [b0 sym('b',[1 5])];
f = a0*k0/sum(b.*x.^[1:4 4 5])
pf = feval(symengine,'partfrac',f,x)
pretty(expand(pf))
```

which returns

```
pf =
    a0 k0   a0 b1 k0   a0 b2 k0 x   a0 b3 k0 x    a0 b4 k0 x    a0 b5 k0 x
    ----- - -------- - ---------- - ----------- - ----------- - -----------
     b0 x      #1          #1            #1            #1            #1

    where

               2                    2          3          3          4
       #1 == b0  + b0 b1 x + b0 b2 x  + b0 b3 x  + b0 b4 x  + b0 b5 x
```

I recommend reading about the options for the `partfrac` function. You can use the [`'Full'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/partfrac.html#partfrac-full) option to expand into linear factors, but the example above doesn't do so simply with arbitrary coefficients (you should use [`assumptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions.html) if you know anything about there values and domains). You can read more about calling MuPAD functions from within Matlab [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/calling-mupad-functions-from-matlab.html).

If you have numeric rather than symbolic coefficients, you should use `residue` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/residue.html)) instead. Read [more here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/partial-fraction-expansions.html).